# How do I find the creator of a table in Vertica ? (Given that the owner was changed)

Tags: sql, vertica

The owner of a table in a Vertica was changed using the command below:

```
ALTER TABLE t33 OWNER TO Bob;
```

Now, I want to know who created this table, since the owner is different from the creator, where do I find that ?

P.S. I tried to go through the log history, but it doesn't hold "create table"statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about...

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE public.stack1 ( ID INTEGER ) ;
CREATE TABLE
SQL> ALTER TABLE public.stack1 OWNER TO mauro ;
ALTER TABLE
SQL> SELECT start_timestamp, user_name, request  
     FROM v_monitor.query_requests 
     WHERE request_type = 'DDL' 
     ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 2;
        start_timestamp        | user_name |                   request                   
-------------------------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------
 2018-05-09 14:13:50.57512-04  | dbadmin   | ALTER TABLE public.stack1 OWNER TO mauro ;
 2018-05-09 14:13:06.348753-04 | dbadmin   | CREATE TABLE public.stack1 ( ID INTEGER ) ;
(2 rows)
```